# Angular calendar ui, load events from database

Tags: angularjs, calendar

I started Angular js recently, and for a project, i have to use calendar-ui to manage events from database.

I managed to use the calendar correctly, using first events create manually. I tried now to bind with datas in database, but it's now comes the problem.

Here is my code :

```
$scope.eventsTab = [];
$scope.events = {};    
$http({
        url: "myurl",
        method: "POST",
        data: postData,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.eventsTab.push({type:'session',title: data.title,start: new Date(y, m, 11, 15, 0),end: new Date(y, m, 20, 17, 30),url: 'http://google.com/'});
            $scope.events = {
                    color: 'orange',
                    textColor: 'white',
                    events: $scope.eventsTab
            };
    });
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

And this is not working, the event is not loaded in my calendar. I think it is a problem dues to asynchronous matters, because if i put the code from "success" function juste before the following line

```
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

, the events appears in the calendar.

A last thing, when i use debug, i see correctly the data form the database .

Could you help me please?

Thanks !

**Edit 1**

If i put the code like this

```
$http({
    url: "myurl",
    method: "POST",
    data: postData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function (data) {
        $scope.eventsTab.push({type:'session',title: data.title,start: new Date(y, m, 11, 15, 0),end: new Date(y, m, 20, 17, 30),url: 'http://google.com/'});
        $scope.events = {
                color: 'orange',
                textColor: 'white',
                events: $scope.eventsTab
        };
        $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
});
```

I got the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

And with the following code

```
$http({
    url: "myurl",
    method: "POST",
    data: postData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function (data) {
        $scope.eventsTab.push({type:'session',title: data.title,start: new Date(y, m, 11, 15, 0),end: new Date(y, m, 20, 17, 30),url: 'http://google.com/'});
        $scope.events = {
                color: 'orange',
                textColor: 'white',
                events: $scope.eventsTab
        };
        $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
});
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

No error, but the same problem : the event is not displayed in the calendar.

Comment: Your assessment of problem is correct. Move `$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];` inside `success` so you are making the assignment when the data actually exists

Comment: Indeed, i arleady tried this ! But when i move `$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];`, i got the error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. And if i put this line in the twho places, no error but the event is not displayed .

Comment: Structure of the data may not be correct for the calendar. Shouldn't $scope.events be an array? Not sure why it is object with `color` and `events` inside it

Comment: It seems i can use both. $scope.events allows me to customize the render of this event. But the fact is that i can display an event in the same way without database, so i don't think it's the problem.

Comment: are you sure data structure coming from server is the same?

Comment: In fact, in my trials, i only used data construct by myself. I know i receive good datas, i don't think it's the problem. In this example, even with a string replacing the "data.title", nothing new. A bad strcuture would have generated me errors i think.

Comment: but it is generating errors. In browser console compare the complete structure of your manual version to the one created from server

Comment: The generated error (which appears in one case) is due to the fact that $scope.eventSources requires to be set. In this case, i got a result from the server, but i don't use it to fill the calendar. The problem is just that when i try to create it through $http request, it doesn't work, if not, it works. Sorry maybe i'm not clear.

Comment: ok.. try setting at top `$scope.eventSources =[];` then inside success push the new data into empty array

Comment: It doesn't work, badly :/

Comment: Suggest you go back to examples where they modify data sources. I can't see the data you are working with or logs in console

Comment: I followed this one initially, but i didn't see other tutorials. Thanks for your help and time anyway !

Comment: Hmm, i did'nt manage to do it :/ I must do something wrong, really frustrating.

Comment: $scope.eventsStagiaire = {
    url : "./webservices/stagiaires/getAllEventsByStagiaire",
    type : 'POST',
    data: {  
     id: objectId,
          }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a friend managed to do it in a other way :

```
$scope.events = {
                url : "./webservices/getAllEvents",
                type : 'POST',
                data: {  
                   id: objectId,
                }   
};
```

It works, so thanks to Gabin :)